# In App Purchase Receipt Data return nil

Tags: objective-c, in-app-purchase, receipt, receipt-validation

I have get my In app purchase code set up and i can perform purchase successfully. And when i try to retrieve receipt data with this

```
NSData *dataReceipt = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL]];
NSString *receipt = [dataReceipt base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
```

I get response with nil when calling appStoreReceiptURL, does anyone know what is the possible root cause? i'm running out of my mind trouble shooting this.

Comment: can  you split it up and figure out what call returns nil. the 'appStoreReceiptURL' or the 'dataWithContentsOfURL:' or 'base64EncodedStringWithOptions:'

Comment: that'd help diagnose the issue a bit

Comment: Hi, i have edited my question, thanks for reminding

Answer (score 0):

if the path is nil this app wasnt purchased from appstore:

"For an application purchased from the App Store, use this application bundle property to locate the receipt."